# Webview, hide or show virtual keyboard only for certain input fields

Tags: javascript, webview

I am writing codes for web-based POS software using HTML,PHP, javascript, etc.
I am then accessing it on PC, chrome browser AND android app on webview.

I am struggling to control the virtual keyboard popup as I desire.

I have 2 input fields

1. with id "searchBox" for barcode search, where it is automatically focused after every action so that user can keep using the barcode scanner.
2. with id "manualSearchBox" for user to manually type in product name or barcode

In my adnroid webview, code works as intended, however everytime "searchBox" is focused,
annoying keyboard pops up.
If I disable on-screen keyboard, it still reads input from barcode scanner,
however, when user wants to search manually with input field "manualSearchBox", no keyboard is shown.

How do I detect input field focus for certain input field and either:

1. Disable keyboard popup when "searchBox" field was focused
2. or disable keyboard in device setting, but call for keyboard only when "manualSearchBox" is focused?

P.S I have some experience in html,php but 0 experience in android app development, hence I am trying to make an app using webview... :(